# Java generic interfaces

Tags: java, class, interface

I have generic class type, T as follow:

```
class MyClass<T>
```

Also I know that T is interface with only one method inside but I don't know what interface, I can't write this:

```
class MyClass< T extends TheInterface >
```

So is there a way to invoke this method?

```
public void callMe(T me, Object...params){
    // How can I invoke T interface method?
}
```

I been trying this:

```
public void callMe(T me, Object... params) {
// methods.length is 244, just as in my activity class
        Method[] methods = me.getClass().getMethods(); 
        try {
            methods[0].invoke(me, params);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;


        }
}
```

But it's not working

**Edit:** I posted new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088507/java-signals-events-pattern) that explain why I need this for

Comment: what's not working? Error message please

Comment: Not being able to know in advance what interface (or super interface) you will get sounds very much like a problem in the design. Relying on reflection to call a method is rarely a good strategy. My personal experience suggests that you should find a way to improve the design (maybe use the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)) rather than trying to call a method which you don't even know the name at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to write:

```
class MyClass< T extends TheInterface >
```

With this information, the compiler know that T have an operation named `callMe`

Comment: Ok. Can you reconsider the design to make this approach possible?

Comment: No I can't, each time is going to be a different interface with nothing in common

Comment: @Babibu Each time it's going to be a different interface with nothing in common, but each interface will have exactly one method that always needs to be invoked?

Comment: @Babibu:  please provide more information of what you are planning to achieve so we get a better picture of how to implement it. Where are the interfaces coming from?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.  Why do you want this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, are you looking for the `Strategy` pattern?

Comment: No, it's not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change declaration inside MyClass then you can just typecast it.

```
    public void callMe(T me, Object... params) {
        Someinterface instance = (Someinterface) me;
        list.callMe(me, params);
    }
```

But still declaring it like below should be the best solution

```
class MyClass<T extends Someinterface >
```

Below is the simple demonstration of how to do it using `reflection`

```
 class MyClass<T> {
    public void callMe(T me, Object... params) throws SecurityException,
            NoSuchMethodException {
        // How can I invoke T interface method?
        Method size = me.getClass().getMethod("size", null);
        Method add = me.getClass().getMethod("add", Object.class);

        try {
            add.invoke(me, 10);
            System.out.println(size.invoke(me, params));

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
    }
}


    MyClass<List> myclass = new MyClass<List>();
    myclass.callMe(new ArrayList(), null);
```

Output :

```
  1
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by typecast it. I also do not know that name of that method, so I can't invoke it by name like in your example with "size" and "add"